# Странный автор метки

Tags: дефект, поддержка, метки, описание-метки, создание-метки

В метке [express](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express) Bim Bam указан как автор.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в истории метки не вижу его вообще.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания метки достаточно поставить её на любой вопрос. А в истории отображаются только те, кто писал к ней описание.

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос, почему не у всех меток указан автор?

Comment: @Suvitruf, возможно автора недавно добавили - он только у свежих меток отображается.

Comment: Как насчёт добавления красной метки в вопрос?

Comment: @alexolut, какой?

Comment: @Qwertiy кто из нас модератор? :)